# Read_csv with quotechar within column content?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to read a csv into dataframe using pandas but the csv delimiters (,) & quotechar (") also appear within the column content:

**"id","TestId","NameId","Description"**

"Testing","GoodDay","James Cafe","Testing the data file, Journey"s Man" CRLF

Got this error:

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line xxyy, saw 5
```

I have tried specifying the delimiters and quotechar but doesn't work.

```py
data = pd.read_csv(file_name, quotechar='"', delimiter = ",")
```

Comment: If read_csv is unable to parse your data consider using the `csv` module directly. It provides more options to fine tune the parser.

Comment: Looks like Journey"s should be Journey's.

Comment: Use a double quote to escape the double quote in Journey"s: Journey""s